# Netlogo patch documentation;

Tags: netlogo

How do I set a region of patches to a specific color and name them?

```
ask patches pycor < -11 and pycor > 11 and pxcor < -11 and pxcor > 11 [
    set pcolor orange ]
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to explain what's wrong with your sample code, and how you want it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Here I've used `let` to make `region` be a local variable, but you could add it to `globals` instead if you wanted. (This is my guess at what you might mean by "name them".)

```
let region patches with [pycor > -11 and pycor < 11 and pxcor > -11 and pxcor < 11
ask region [ set pcolor orange ]
```

note that I flipped your `<` and `>` directions -- that's me taking my best guess at what you might have meant.